# Relative Path is not working in WIX and XML and showing the error "The System cannot find the file"

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7

I am building my WIX project with version 4.0 from visual studio 2017 (Votive).

In the .wxs file, for the merge element the relative path is not working and showing the error "The System cannot find the file".
Below is the code:

```
<Merge Id= "Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86" Language="1033" DiskId="1" SourceFile="\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm" />
```

I tried SourceFile path with different ways but even those are also not working:

```
SourceFile="..\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm" 
SourceFile="\\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm" 
SourceFile="\MsVCDlls\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm" 
SourceFile="..\MsVCDlls\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm"
```

If i give the complete absolute path like as shown below then it is working:

```
SourceFile="E:\Code\EMR\Install\MsVCDlls\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm"
```

Note:
I am running the project from C:\Users\source\EMR
and "Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm" is located in the below path:
E:\Code\EMR\Install\MsVCDlls\Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm

Is it due to different paths?

Do I need to include any namespace?
Please help me how to give the relative path?

Answer (score 0):

***Drive Letters***: You can not use relative paths when the file you point to is located on another drive (letter). Can we ask why you have some files on **`C:\`** and some on **`E:\`**? Could you move it all to one main location? Then you can use relative paths.